# Unable to locate a specific shape in Visio

Tags: microsoft-office, microsoft-visio, microsoft-visio-2013, shapes

I'm trying to create (convert) a Visio architecture diagram from an existing image which is available in the format of JPG extension.  My question is, in this complete architecture diagram which I'm trying to convert, there is one specific shape/symbol which I couldn't able to locate/find in the Visio stencil.  Can somebody help me in locating this shape/symbol either inside Visio stencil or from any external stencils/symbols?

[image]

**NOTE:** I'm using Visio Professional 2013.

Answer (score 1):

It looks to me to be a symbol for a state machine. The shape shows three states with events connecting them. The outer circle just provides a frame for the shape.